# Kanban flow - query

Tags: workflow, agile, scrum, kanban

I am planning to implement Kanban in our team. We currently use Scrum. We will have a story in backlog and a developer assigns the story to him/her and completes the development. Then QA engineer will change the assignee of the same story to his/her name and completes the QA and deploys.IS this the recommended way of changing the assignee of the same story ticket as it flows from backlog to dev to qa and finally to closure. IF yes, how to track individual efforts?

Answer (score 1):

Kanban isn't focused on tracking individual effort. It's main prupose is to reduce the WIP.

I think it's better to put a story in status "to test" than a QA tester picks one to test. If the test passes than the story is done, if not the QA puts it back in "in progess" while assigning the story to the developer who developed it at first place.